# dynamic data attribute with not: selector

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to remove a disable attribute from several inputs, except that ones that have a data attribute with certain value.

If i set a data attribute directly in the html, everything works fine, but if i set dynamically in the dom, its stop to work.

js:

```
$("input[name='title']").data("notallow", 0);
$("input[name='cod']").data("notallow", 0);

console.log($("input[name='cod']").data()); // data is seted

$("body").on("click", "button", function(){
    $("input").not("[data-notallow='0']").attr("disabled", false);
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xvwMc/)

what i'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `data`, you aren't dynamically setting an attribute to the HTML, jQuery actually updates the element's "data store" with the new property you just set.

So if you want to make that `notallow` available for "querying", you shouldn't use `.data()` (or even `.prop()`). You should use `.attr()`, this is the function that actually creates the attribute:

```
$("input[name='title']").attr("data-notallow", 0);
$("input[name='cod']").attr("data-notallow", 0);
```

Your fiddle, updated, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xvwMc/2/).

Note: the same way, you should use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` for enabling/disabling.

Note 2: `.data()`, the data store, is really powerful: you can even store objects. Having this in mind, at least for me, makes it clearer of why the `.data()` function does not really create a DOM `data-` attribute (how would one store an object?).

Answer (score 2):

@acdcjunior summarized it pretty well. However, you can still filter on `data` stored in the jQuery `$.cache` as well (as in your example where the `data()` method is used):

```
$('input').filter(function(i, el){
    return $(el).data('notallow') !== 0;
}).prop({ disabled: false });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xvwMc/3/